# HTML5 Canvas how to make image can resizable by Kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, html, resize, kineticjs

I have add image function :

```
$("ul#img a").click(function(){
    addProduct( $('img', this) );            
});

   function addProduct( imgObj ){

   var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var imageObj = new Image();       //createimage
    imageObj.onload = function() { 
      var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 53,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
        image: imageObj,
              draggable: true,
        name: "image"
      });
        // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(image);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
```

=========== End function add Image to canvas ============

```
    image.on("mouseover", function(){
    var imagelayer = this.getLayer();
    document.body.style.cursor = "move"; 
    this.setStrokeWidth(2);
    this.setStroke("white"); //It's border of image when hover

    layer.draw();   
    writeMessage(messageLayer, "Delete it");}); //DeleteItem

    image.on("mouseout", function(){ 

    var imagelayer = this.getLayer();
    document.body.style.cursor = "default"; 
    this.setStrokeWidth(0);
    this.setStroke("transparent");
    layer.draw();  
    writeMessage(messageLayer, "");});

    image.on("dblclick dbltap", function(){
    layer.remove(image);
    layer.clear();
    layer.draw();});};

    imageObj.src = imgObj.attr('src'); }
```

=========== End Event of Image ============

This code can add image to canvas ,can dragable but cant resizable
How to make this image can resizable?
Please explain to me please

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kinetic elements do not have a built-in way to let the user resize.**

Here's code to let the user drag the right edge of the image to resize the image:

- Listen for mousedown, mouseup and mousemove
- If mousedown occurs on the right edge of the image, save that mouse x,y,
- On each mousemove, scale the image by the aspect ratio created by the distance the mouse has moved.

**Example code to get you started:**

```js
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 350,
  height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var kImage;
var startRight=-1;
var startWidth=0;
var startHeight=0;

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";
function start(){
  kImage = new Kinetic.Image({
    image:img,
    x:10,
    y:10,
    width:img.width,
    height:img.height,
  });
  layer.add(kImage);
  layer.draw();
}


$(stage.getContent()).on('mousedown', function (event) {
  var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
  var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
  var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
  var ipos=kImage.position();
  var isize=kImage.getSize();
  var right=ipos.x+isize.width;
  if(mouseX>right-10 && mouseX<right+10){
    startRight=mouseX;
    startWidth=isize.width;
    startHeight=isize.height;
  }
});


$(stage.getContent()).on('mouseup', function (event) {
  startRight=-1;
});


$(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function (event) {
  if(startRight>=0){
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
    var dx=mouseX-startRight;
    var scaleFactor=(mouseX-(startRight-startWidth))/startWidth;
    kImage.width(startWidth*scaleFactor);
    kImage.height(startHeight*scaleFactor);
    layer.draw();
  }
});
```

```css
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.2.0/kinetic.js"></script>
<h4>Drag the right border of the image to resize<br>it while maintaining aspect ratio.</h4>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: i can't do that @.@
if image can dragable ,will cant resize.

Comment: No problem...You can determine if the user intends a drag or intends a resize. If the mouse position in mousedown is inside the resize edge then the user is intending a resize. To resize, temporarily disable dragging using `myObject.draggable(false)`. Then re-enable the draggable property after the resizing is over. Cheers!